# SignalR Core: invalid negotiation response received in a .Net app

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I get this error when connecting to a .Net Core SignalR server with a .Net Framework SignalR Core client. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

What helped me is adding this to app.config.

`<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>`